# Get customfield option

Tags: jira, velocity

Does anyone know how get a custom field option using a velocity template.

I am trying to set a default description based on issue type and custom field option can anyone help.

I have tried using Java script but no success

Comment: We want to see your code attempts ...

Answer (score 1):

Using the Jira REST API you can use the method `http://example.com:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?expand=projects.issuetypes.fields` ([described here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/5.1.8/#id91070)). This will give you the detailed information about available issue types, the custom fields and their specific options.

Answer (score 0):

```
`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
issueType = document.getElementById("issuetype-field");
requestType = document.getElementById("customfield_11504");
description = document.getElementById("description");
if (issueType)
{
   target = document.getElementById == "2";
   // Hide the Target Field if issueType isn't Service Request
   if (requestType)
   {
      target = document.getElementById("customfield_11504");
      // Hide Target Field if requestType isn't Deployment  
        if (issueType.value != "2") target.style.display = 'none';
      issueType.onchange = function()
      {
         if (this.value == "2")
         {
            requestType.onchange = function()
            {
               if (this.value == "11501")
               {
                  description.style.display = '';
                  description.value = 'Default Text for Deployment';
                  requestType.onchange = function()
                  {
                     if (this.value == "11900")
                     {
                        description.style.display = '';
                        description.value = 'Default Text for Enhancement';
                        requestType.onchange = function()
                        {
                           if (this.value == "11901")
                           {
                              description.style.display = '';
                              description.value = 'Default Text for New Account';
                           }
                        }
                        ;
                     }
                  }
                  ;
               }
            }
            ;
         }
      }
      ;
   }`
```